Cracked Hawthorne sapling growing leaves on trunk
A couple years ago, I planted a Crimson Cloud Hawthorne sapling. After the first Colorado winter, I noticed a sizable crack form at the base of the trunk. It still grew leaves on the branches, but it also tried to grow leaves/branches below the crack, which I would prune off. This seems to be happening again this year. Is this related to the crack, and is there something i can do to fix it?

More pics available if helpful, but I didn't want to create extra noise.
